# Jasmine , check value on an input form control

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular2-forms

I am new to Jasmine unit tests. I am trying to write a unit test for one of my form control which is of type='text'. My form control has an id="code" and after setting few predefined values I am expecting my control to have value '123' in my test.  test 1 pass but test 2 fails. Someone pls explain to me what's the difference between these two queries?? Thanks,

```
    1. expect(component.myForm.value.code).toBe('123'); // this pass
    2. expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#code')).nativeElement.value).toEqual('123'); 
// this fail  with warning: Expected undefined to equal '123'.
```

Comment: did you call `fixture.detectChanges()`

Comment: Thanks @Aravind for taking time to look at my question. I figured out the issue, I had two elements which has got the same id, 'code'. So when jasmine runner tries to find the element by css, it was getting the  first one. So I have added more specific way to get the element I am expecting by    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#code input')).nativeElement.value).toEqual('123'); - and that worked.